# Java: Automatically Update a Checkbox in JTable when Another Checkbox is Clicked

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I want every checkbox in the JTable in the EventYearMatchingUnitPanel class to be selected automatically when a checkbox in the JTable in EventYearMatchingWindow is clicked.

clicking the "unit 9" checkbox in the first picture (https://ibb.co/fsqtrQ) should automatically select all 5 checkboxes in the second picture (https://ibb.co/f8ja5k)

I used the tableChanged() method in TabelModelListener to detect if a checkbox is clicked. When I click the checkbox, it changes the value of the other checkboxes (from Boolean.FALSE to Boolean.TRUE), but the checkboxes don't update (don't physically show the checkmarks).

```
//for the first JTable
public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e){
    int row = e.getFirstRow();
    int column = e.getColumn();
    TableModel model = (TableModel)e.getSource();
    String columnName = model.getColumnName(column);
    Object thatValue = model.getValueAt(row, column);
    data[row][column] = thatValue;
    for(int i = 0; i < unitPanels[row].getNumRows(); i++){
        unitPanels[row].setToSelectedState(i);
    }
} 

//for the second JTable
public void setToSelectedState(int row){    
    data[row][0] = Boolean.TRUE;
    model.fireTableCellUpdated(row, 0);
}
```

Here's a bigger picture of the code:

```
public class EventYearMatchingWindow extends JFrame implements 
TableModelListener
{
    private boolean columnHeaderClicked;
    private ArrayList<Category> categories;
    private JPanel mainPanel, listPanel, buttonPanel;
    private ArrayList<Item> selectedItems;
    private EventYearMatchingItemChoosing[] unitPanels;
    Object data[][];
    public EventYearMatchingWindow(ArrayList<Category> c){
        ...
        String[] columnNames = {"Include?", ""};   
        data = new Object[6][2];
        for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
            data[i][0] = Boolean.FALSE;
            data[i][1] = "Unit " + (i+8);
        }
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames) {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
            @Override
            public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
                if (columnIndex == 0){
                    return Boolean.class;
                }
                return super.getColumnClass(columnIndex);
            }
        };

        JTable table = new JTable(model);
        table.getModel().addTableModelListener(this);
        table.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
        ....
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                int row = table.rowAtPoint(evt.getPoint());
                int col = table.columnAtPoint(evt.getPoint());
                if (row == -1 && col >= 0){
                    columnHeaderClicked = true;
                }
                if (row >= 0 && col == 1 && !columnHeaderClicked) {
                    mainPanel.removeAll();

                    System.out.println(unitPanels[row].getData()[0][0]);
                    unitPanels[row].revalidate();
                    unitPanels[row].repaint();

                    mainPanel.add(unitPanels[row]);
                    JPanel nButtonPanel = new JPanel();
                    Button back = new Button("Back");
                    nButtonPanel.add(back);
                    back.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                            mainPanel.removeAll();
                            mainPanel.add(listPanel);
                            mainPanel.add(buttonPanel);
                            mainPanel.revalidate();
                            repaint();
                        }
                    });
                    mainPanel.add(nButtonPanel);
                    mainPanel.revalidate();
                    repaint();
                }
            }
        });   
    }
    public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e){
        int row = e.getFirstRow();
        int column = e.getColumn();
        TableModel model = (TableModel)e.getSource();
        String columnName = model.getColumnName(column);
        Object thatValue = model.getValueAt(row, column);
        data[row][column] = thatValue;
        for(int i = 0; i < unitPanels[row].getNumRows(); i++){
            unitPanels[row].setToSelectedState(i);
        }
    } 
}
```

And:

```
public class EventYearMatchingItemChoosing extends JPanel implements TableModelListener
{
    Category category;
    private boolean columnHeaderClicked;
    private int size;
    private ArrayList<Item> items;
    private Object[][] data;
    DefaultTableModel model;
    public EventYearMatchingItemChoosing(String s, ArrayList<Category> c){
        ...
        String[] columnNames = {"Include?", "Event", "Year"};   
        data = new Object[size][3]
        for(int i = 0; i < category.getItems().size(); i++){ 
            if(!category.getItems().get(i).getEvent().equals("") && !category.getItems().get(i).getYear().equals("")){
                data[i][0] = Boolean.FALSE;
                data[i][1] = category.getItems().get(i).getEvent();            
                data[i][2] = category.getItems().get(i).getYear();   
            }
        }    

        model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames) {   
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;   
            @Override
            public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
                if (columnIndex == 0){
                    return Boolean.class;
                }
                return super.getColumnClass(columnIndex);
            }    
        };
        JTable table = new JTable(model);
        table.getModel().addTableModelListener(this);
        ...
    }
    ...
    public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e){
        int row = e.getFirstRow();
        int column = e.getColumn();
        TableModel model = (TableModel)e.getSource();
        String columnName = model.getColumnName(column);
        Object thatValue = model.getValueAt(row, column);
        data[row][column] = thatValue;
    }
    public void setToSelectedState(int row){    
        data[row][0] = Boolean.TRUE;
        model.fireTableCellUpdated(row, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: The small, incomplete snippet of code you posted wouldn't compile. Post a minimal, complete example reproducing the problem.

Comment: Thanks, I updated it with the entire code.

Comment: [mcve] has "Minimal" in it, which is the opposite of "entire code". Just FYI.

Comment: Thank you...I tried simplifying it by taking out some unrelated code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but the checkboxes don't update (don't physically show the checkmarks).

```
data[row][0] = Boolean.TRUE;
```

Don't ever access the data Array. The data Array is used to create the DefaultTableModel and then the data is copied from the Array to the data structure used by the DefaultTableModel (which happens to be a Vector of Vectors).

The end result is that the data in the TableModel is never changed.

The code should be:

```
model.setValueAt(Boolean.TRUE, row, 0);
```